# Prism 4 + IoC samples for WP7 or WP8?

Tags: c#, ninject, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, prism

I'm looking for best practices for dependency injection on WP7/PW8 using Prism and preferrably Ninject.
Is there any samples covering what usage Prism can do with the IoC container, and best practices for setting it up?

(We've got it running currently in a rudimentary way, but we are using Ninject as a resource locator and I'm not too comfortable with that solution. It feels like there are better ways.)

Comment: If you're using Prism best go for Unity for DI, imho

Comment: @Jeroen But Unity isn't supported for Windows Phone?

Comment: ok, didn't know that, never worked on Wphone :)